# managing scope objects populated from remote services in angular js

Tags: angularjs, crud

I have a function that saves a person object to a database from controller A. When the person service returns a successful promise I emit a "personListUpdated" event up to $rootScope where controller B is listening for this event. When its received with (see code below) the view doesnt reflect the changes made to the model. I imagine there is a good reason for this, I just dont know what it is.

```
$rootScope.$on('personListUpdated' function() {   
    PersonService.getAllPeople().then(function(people) {
        $scope.people = people;
     })
});
```

Comment: We would have to see where the bindings to the view are done.

Comment: Use your debugger. Put a breakpoint on the second line to see if the event is received. Put a breakpoint on third line to see if the promise is resolved. Check what the people variable contains.

Comment: What type of promise is returned by `getAllPeople()`? Should the code in the `.then` callback actually be wrapped in a `$scope.$apply` to force a digest of your page?

Comment: that's interesting. Ill give that a try

Comment: an up-to-date list of all people is returned by the promise

Comment: refreshing the page achieves the desired effect..

Comment: I can get a simplified mockup of what you're describing working here: http://plnkr.co/edit/sBXXQavXPOHOatmOGZBZ?p=preview. It's hard to tell what's wrong without more information. Do you know for sure that the event is firing, that you are catching it, and that your `getAllPeople().then` handler is running? Have you checked via a debugger or console.log that these things are happening in the order you expect them to?